# Visual Studio - Create Class library targeting .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-library, .net-core

How do I create a class library targeting .Net Core in visual studio 2015?
I found this getting started “[guide](https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/)”, which shows how to create a new .Net Core project using the *dotnet* command line tool.
Do I need to create somehow a VS project manual based on the generated files (*project.json*…)?
Is there a way to create a .Net Core DLL inside of VS without using the “dotnet” tool?

Comment: If you're using the `dotnet` command line tool, you're ahead of the release candidates... I don't know whether there's VS support for that. Within the RC1 "dnx" world you can definitely use the VS plugin for ASP.NET vnext to create a class library package. Do you have that installed? (In New Project / Templates / Visual C# / Web, is there a "Class Library (Package)" option?

Comment: Nice! Yes I’ve installed that.. and creating a project worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For .net Core RC 2 if you have installed the [tools](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798481)  then you can simply go: File -> Visual C# -> New project -> .Net Core using visual studio. I am currently working on a guide to get started with these kind of projects [here](https://github.com/LRPalacios/net-core-get-started) if you want so see

[image]

Comment: Can you please this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004339/net-standard-vs-net-core-app-when-creating-net-core-project-using-console-or) , when you create a class library it doesn't reference .NET Core

Comment: I've gave you an answer, i hope it's helpful to you